# Constructing QTextStream in a loop causes file to incorrectly read data

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading a `QFile` in the most common way the only difference being due to to my programs architecture I initialized `QTextStream` on a file inside the reading loop.

To my surprise this has lead to the `QFile` incorrectly telling the file position  and as a result of such the `QTextStream` is reading just one line or stopping at seemingly random line number depending on the file.

**Why does `QTextStream` behave in this way? I could not find any reference in the documentation about this sort of issue. Is there something I have missed?**

**Code Example**

This is the error code I was using (cut out from the architecture and simplified)

```
QFile file;
QString line;
int interationCount = 0;
file.setFileName(fileName);

if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    while(true)
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        if(stream.readLineInto(&line) == false)
            break; //Or return

        std::count << "Line "<< interationCount << ": " << line << "\n";
        interationCount++;
    }
}
```

**Input and output**

Given a file of numbers raging from 1 to 35 ordered on each line in a text format like so:

```
1
2
3
...
35
```

The algorithm reads just a single line of output while reading all of the lines is expected.

**Output:**

```
Line 0: 1
```

**Expected output:**

```
Line 0: 1
Line 1: 2
Line 2: 3
...
Line 34: 35
```

Comment: If you notice in your first code in each iteration you are creating a new QTextStream. Move `QTextStream stream(&file);` before `while(true)`

Comment: Well I already know the reason why my code didn't work. I am just curious about the reason why so and wanted to share this problem so people who might have a similar issue will find an answer.

Comment: Then you must publish only one question and one response at the beginning, that is allowed in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. If it's just a question, I'll probably erase it. Generally, when you provide a question + answer, it must be interesting. IMHO your question is not, since it is a trivial error. You say: *will find an answer*, but since there is no answer in the SO nobody can find it

Comment: Okay I will provide the answer and edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QTextStream` doesn't read data from the underlying `QIODevice` byte by byte, but has an internal decoded buffer, used both to avoid paying the cost of the repeated virtual call, and to do the encoding conversion on bigger chunks.

This means that, once you start using it on a `QIODevice`, it may have read from it way more than you read from the `QTextStream`; this is actually explained [in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextstream.html#details):

> Since the text stream uses a buffer, you should not read from the stream using the implementation of a superclass. For instance, if you have a `QFile` and read from it directly using `QFile::readLine()` instead of using the stream, the text stream's internal position will be out of sync with the file's position.

By continuously reading and destroying the `QTextStream` you are always getting data from the file according to the read buffer size, and then discarding all that you didn't read from the text stream.

Answer (score 0):

**Repeated constructing** of `QTextStream` due to reasons answered by @MatteoItalia **causes this error.**

The fixed code looks like this:

```
QFile file;
QString line;
int interationCount = 0;

file.setFileName(fileName);

if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    while(stream.readLineInto(&line))
    {
        std::count << "Line "<< interationCount << ": " << line << "\n";
        interationCount++;
    }
}
```

And produces the expected output:

```
Line 0: 1
Line 1: 2
Line 2: 3
...
Line 34: 35
```

**Additional Info**

This error might seem obvious. Of curse repeatedly constructing object inside a loop is a bad practice (both performance wise and because errors like this), but in certain architectures this might not be as obvious.

Consider the following architecture:
parent class called `FileFormat_Parrent` with virtual functions for reading single line of a file that must be overloaded, which could be using a `QTextStream` to do so.

```
class FileFormat_Parrent
{
   public:
       QFile File;
       void* Buffer

   virtual bool ReadSingle() = 0;
   virtual bool WriteSingle() = 0;
};

class FileFormat_Txt : public FileFormat_Parrent
{
   virtual bool ReadSingle() {/*Possibly using QTextStream to do so*/}
   virtual bool WriteSingle() {...}
};

class FileFormat_BinArray : public FileFormat_Parrent
{
   ...
};
```

Then while using these classes a `FileFormat` class would be created in the appropriate child type based on the file type.

These created FileFormats would then be used in a loop iterating between `ReadSingle()` and `WriteSingle()` until either one of them returns false.

This would result in the error code occurring, because the `QTextStream` is repeatedly constructed inside the loop.